# Golang - finding text for each child element separately with PuerkitoBio/goquery

Tags: go, goquery

I am new to Golang and just started learning it. I want to find some information from a site and extract the data that I need. I am using the [PuerkitoBio/goquery package](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) to select elements and read from them. I would like to extract the data from this piece of html:

```
<ul class="cases-counter">
  <li>Cases: <strong>457</strong><br></li>
  <li>Active: <strong>16</strong><br></li>
</ul>
```

And this is the code that I have:

```
doc.Find(".cases-counter").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    text := s.Find("li").Text()
    fmt.Print(i)
    fmt.Printf(text)
})
```

This prints me:

```
0Cases: 457Active: 16
```

How can I print each `li element`'s text separately as two different variables in this example?

Comment: What do you mean as  separately 2 different variables? Can you extend it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
func ExampleNewDocumentFromReader_string() {

    data := `
<html>
    <ul class="cases-counter">
  <li id="Cases">Cases: <strong>457</strong><br></li>
  <li id="Active">Active: <strong>16</strong><br></li>
</ul>
</html>`

    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(strings.NewReader(data))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    doc.Find(".cases-counter").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {

        Cases := s.Find("#Cases").Text()
        Active := s.Find("#Active").Text()
        fmt.Printf("Review %d: %s, %s\n", i, Cases, Active)
    })

}
func main() {
    ExampleNewDocumentFromReader_string()
}
```

Comment: I am scraping this content from the website, so I can't do this